# VLOOKUP wrong result and sort the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a problem with the `vlookup`, I sure that I use the function correctly, but I have a wrong result.

[image]

[image]

I tried also this code, and i have the same problem:

`INDEX('F-CLIENT'!B$2:B$426;EQUIV(Feuil1!C4;('F-CLIENT'!A$2:A$426)))`

For exemple: for the Code "E032" I must have this result

[image]

Comment: what is `RECHERCHEV` function in ENGLISH ?

Comment: It's a `VLOOKUP` function

Comment: I find the solution, i just must to add , in the end of the function `false`

Comment: Now, when i sort it the values of the vlookup are not adapted 

in the beginning:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Qmx.png

after sort:




  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQiX.png

Comment: @Emna you need to sort the whole data not only one column!

Comment: Can you help me plz? I don't find the way to do it from this [office-link]https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: If C4 is in the same sheet as the Formula don't write Feuil1!C4 just write C4 and false

Comment: Try the formula: =Sierreur(RECHEREV(C4;'F-Client'!$A$2:$B$426;2;False),"")

Comment: Feuil1!C4 is preventing the sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this has been resolved for OP in the comments but there is no explanation of the feature.

[image: VLOOKUP arguments]

**Resolution:** Specify the optional `range_lookup` argument at the end of your vlookup
Assign it to `FALSE` (or `0`) to perform an an Exact match.

**Why:**  It is `TRUE` (or `1`) by default. This performs an Approximate match.

Check out the [MSDN documentation on VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) which provides more information on what this does with examples.